# Output full difference between expected and actual list in assertj

Tags: gradle, junit, junit4, assertj

I am using groovy, assertj, junit and gradle. I have a test that contains assertion like that

```
assertThat(actualLongList).isEqualTo(expectedLongList)
```

When I run `gradle test` and those lists are not equal, it generates a test report with an exception like that

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<...ent2",
"element3",
"element4",
"element5]"]> but was:<...ent2",
"element4,
"element5",
"element6]"]>
```

Can I somehow configure exception output format so it will fully output both lists?

```
 org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:
<["element1",
"element2",
"element3",
"element3",
"element4",]> but was:,
<["element1",
"element2",
"element4",
"element5",
"element6",]>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how `org.junit.ComparisonFailure#getMessage()` works (see [javadoc](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/ComparisonFailure.html#getMessage())).
If you want to have a full (better ?) description, you can use `containsOnlyElementsOf` (or any `containsXxxElementsOf` you see fit), you will get something like:

`java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting:
  <["element1",
    "element2",
    "element3",
    "element4",
    "element5",
    "element6",
    "element7",
    "element8",
    "element9"]>
to contain only:
  <["element1",
    "element2",
    "element3",
    "element4",
    "element5",
    "element6",
    "element7",
    "element8",
    "element0"]>
elements not found:
  <["element0"]>
and elements not expected:
  <["element9"]>`